# HTML Setting Active with different background colour

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my HTML List:

```
            <ul id="navlist">
                <li class="item1"><a href="#">One</a></li>
                <li class="item2"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                <li class="item3"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                <li class="item4"><a href="#">Four</a></li>
                <li class="item5"><a href="#">Five</a></li>
                <li class="item6"><a href="#">Six</a></li>

            </ul>
```

Each `.itemx` has a different background colour, so I need the active state to take into account the `class`.

Obviously something like:

```
                <li class="item6" id="active"><a href="#">Six</a></li>

#active.item6 {
background: red;
}
```

Would work but IE6 doesnt like chained items in CSS so doesnt work when other items are set out in the CSS.

Can I do this with jQuery where each item has a different background colour when 'active?

Comment: what do you mean by active? are you talking about the active state or when the li items are shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element can have multiple classes, like this:

```
<li class="item6 active"><a href="#">Six</a></li>
```

Then you can create the normal and "active" versions:

```
.item6 {
  background: green;
}
.item6.active {
  background: red;
}
```

The second rule applies if it has *both* classes, then just [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), or [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) where needed.  This isn't a jQuery thing, just a CSS thing...you're only using jQuery for the class add/remove portion, the CSS part works without JavaScript at all.